# All my materials look like blobs

Tags: materials

I'm not sure what I pushed, but all of the sudden, all of my materials look like blobs and don't match the edges.

[image]

Sorry, I'm brand new to Blender and I did try googling this, but my 3d modeling vocab is bad enough that I wasn't sure what question to ask.

Comment: You've probably breaked the mesh into individual pieces (for the materials), and still using a subdivision modifier. You can remove the subdivision, or join all pieces back together [crtl+j], and in edit mode join all duplicated vertices [ctrl+v > remove doubles].

Comment: It was a subdivision modifyer. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material showing on wrong faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/material-showing-on-wrong-faces) and [uv mapping not filling faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/uv-mapping-not-filling-faces) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88390/material-of-mesh-doesnt-match-the-render-because-of-subdivision-surface?noredirect=1&lq=1